# Finite element method for odd order DE

Tags: finite-element

What are theoretical hurdles in applying Galerikin method on, say, first order time dependent ODE?

Is there no way we can form an inner product??

Comment: Isn't 1st order ODE easy enough to solve analytically? Do you have a specific equation in mind?

Comment: agree but the reason for our inability to handle it are probably same as for 3 order, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that you can form an inner product there. Nevertheless, there are other methods that do not use the same space for test and trial functions, e.g., [Petrov-Galerkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrov%E2%80%93Galerkin_method) methods. The problem here is that the matrix is not symmetric anymore.

You can also use Least Squares FEM. For this you have
$$\mathcal{L}u=f\quad \text{in }\Omega\quad \text{and}\quad \mathcal{R}u=g\quad \text{on } \partial\Omega$$
where, $\mathcal{L}u=g$ and $\mathcal{R}u=g$ is the boundary condition. Then, you form the functional
$$J(u;f,g) =\Vert \mathcal{L}u-f\Vert^2 + \Vert \mathcal{R}u-g\Vert^2$$
and solve the minimization problem
$$\min_{u\in S} J(u;f,g)$$
and you end up with a system of the form
$$(\mathcal{L}v,\mathcal{L}u) + (\mathcal{R}v,\mathcal{R}u) = (\mathcal{L}v,f)  + (\mathcal{R}v,\mathcal{L}f) \forall\ v \in S \enspace .$$
A caveat here is that the norms and inner products are not in the same space. I have seen this method for Quantum Electrodynamics, where the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) is first order, example [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080729633).