# How to solve odd-order differential equations in FEM? Petrov-Galerkin?

Tags: finite-element, reference-request, differential-equations, galerkin

I've recently learned about using weighted residuals with the Galerkin method to numerically approximate even-order differential equations (for linear elements, I'm still a beginner). It seems for odd-order differential equations you cannot use integration by parts to reduce the order of the third-order differential operator.

I've read that the *Petrov-Galerkin* method can approximate these solutions, but I cannot find cogent material on it or examples of it in action. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Third derivatives are a bit odd, and don't appear too often. But first derivatives as in the advection equation are quite common. Learn how these are solved and you will have a good starting point for knowing how to solve 3rd order problems.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/19459/9667)?